# Mediapipe hand model

Tags: python, search, mediapipe

while searching on MediaPipe hands model, architecture
I found they depend on Blaze palm for detection, but I am unable to understand the full Blaze palm architecture [image: BlazePalm]
found in MediaPipe hands paper
especially the parts connected to anchors after decoder
any one have an explain will be appreciated

after dive to the paper they use an encoder-decoder feature extractor similar to FPN for a larger scene-context awareness even for small objects.
but unable to understand the parts 2*16*16 and others connected to anchors
is this a layer between 16*16 layer and anchors genration?